# In BigQuery, how to clusterize Stackoverflow tags?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot, sql-like, dataform

I'm trying to clusterize the Stackoverflow tags from the BigQuery public dataset.
According to one of my data specialists colleagues, the standard procedure is to link each tag to the "nearest" ones.
For that, I'm planning to search the related tags in the excerpt and generate a table with the following columns

For example, considering the following tag infos

| Row | id | tag_name | excerpt | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 61060 | openwrap | OpenWrap is a dependency manager for the .net platform | OpenWrap is a dependency manager for the .net platform. It can be found at http://openwrap.org. |

I would like to generate a table such as

| id | tag_name | .net | dependency manager | java | spring |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61060 | openwrap | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Which would allow me to run a k-means computation.

For that, I would like to use a SQL PIVOT, but I don't understand how.

So far,
my SQL query looks like

```
DECLARE tag_names ARRAY <STRING> ;
SET tag_names = ARRAY ( 
    SELECT tags.tag_name 
    FROM ${ref("stackoverflow_tags_with_non_null_excerpt")} AS tags
);

SELECT *
FROM ${ref("stackoverflow_tags_with_non_null_excerpt")} AS tags
PIVOT(
-- I don't know what I'm doing
)
```

I've never written any PIVOT, so what should I put in considering I would like to run something like "return 1 for each tag which is in my excerpt, 0 otherwise", which should be implemented with `excerpt like "%s{tag}%s" for tag in UNNEST(tag_names)`

Am I far from the good answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array `tag_names` containing all the tag names from your dataset. Then, perform a `CROSS JOIN` between the original table and the unnested tag_names array. This combination pairs each tag with each tag name in the array.

In the SELECT clause, it uses a CASE statement within the MAX aggregation function to determine if the tag_name is present in the excerpt. If it is, it sets is_related to 1; otherwise, it sets it to 0.

Finally, it groups the results by id and tag_name to get the desired format.

This query will give you a table where each row represents a tag, and the columns represent whether that tag is related to each of the other tags based on the presence of the tag name in the excerpt. The is_related column will have 1 if related and 0 if not. You can use this table for clustering or any other analysis you need to perform.

This example query might give you a hint:

```
DECLARE tag_names ARRAY<STRING>;
SET tag_names = ARRAY(
    SELECT tag_name
    FROM ${ref("stackoverflow_tags_with_non_null_excerpt")}
);

-- Use a CROSS JOIN to pair each tag with each tag name in the array
SELECT
    t.id AS id,
    t.tag_name AS tag_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN t.excerpt LIKE CONCAT('%', tn, '%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS is_related
FROM
    ${ref("stackoverflow_tags_with_non_null_excerpt")} AS t
CROSS JOIN
    UNNEST(tag_names) AS tn
GROUP BY
    t.id,
    t.tag_name;
```